# node.js create object from raw http request string

Tags: node.js, parsing, http

I have a raw HTTP request string from which I need to create an object representation.

Instead of reinvent the wheel I was thinking about use the internal http parser to get an instance of [http.IncomingMessage](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage)

## Is it possible?

I think so because string is not so different from a complete stream.

## How to do it?

I had a look on source code and they get a request parser as follow

```
var HTTPParser = process.binding('http_parser').HTTPParser;
var parser = new HTTPParser(HTTPParser.REQUEST)
```

**Edit**

Some progress from a [node.js test](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/857975d5e7e0d7bf38577db0478d9e5ede79922e/test/simple/test-http-parser.js#L95)

```
var request = Buffer(raw);
var parser = new HTTPParser(HTTPParser.REQUEST);

parser.execute(request, 0, request.length);
```

**Edit 2**

Some eventHandlers were missing (all of them)

```
parser.onHeadersComplete = function(res) {
    console.log('onHeadersComplete');
    console.log(res);
};

parser.onBody = function(body) {
    console.log('body done');
    console.log(body.toString());
}

parser.onMessageComplete = function(res) {
    console.log('done');
};
```

Thanks

Comment: I updated my question. I have a "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: localhost\n\n" string, which I need to parse to create an object. The resulting object must be instance of [http.IncomingMessage](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage)

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: The complete workflow until get a IncomingMessage object.

Comment: Why don't you use the `http` module? `require('http').createServer(function(req,res){ ... })` The function gets called each time there is a request. `req` is already an instance of [http.IncomingMessage](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage)

Comment: I don't need an HTTP server to serve requests.  I just beed a parser for HTTP messages.

Comment: You want to serve HTTP requests, but not use an HTTP server... Now read that again and realize that **server** contains **serve**.

Comment: @CoDEmanX: No, you got it wrong. I have a RAW HTTP request (`String`) and I want to parse it to get an `Object`, instance of `http.IncomingMessage`. Now read that again and realize that I didn't write **server** or **serve**

Comment: https://gist.github.com/CoDEmanX/41ae8879afecb9a13a98 ?

Comment: @CoDEmanX you're not getting the point. I **DO NOT** need an HTTP Server nor use Networking. I was looking for a parser like [http-string-parser](https://github.com/PauloASilva/http-string-parser) for Node.js, but why using this when Node.js has a built in parser?

Comment: I assume you added your events between the `new HttpParser(...)` and the `parser.execute`?

Comment: @major-mann: you're right!

Comment: Did this achieve what you were  looking for? If not could you update with what the current issue is with the code you're using?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the `http_parser` module is a low-level callback-based parser. It will send whatever parts of the string it can parse to you via those callbacks, and it is up to you to make an `IncomingMessage` or whatever else you need from them.

I believe something like that might be what you are looking for:

```
var HTTPParser = process.binding('http_parser').HTTPParser;

function parseMessage(request) {
    var _message = {};
    var _parser = new HTTPParser(HTTPParser.REQUEST);

    _parser.onHeadersComplete = function(headers) { 
        _message = headers; 
    }

    _parser.onBody = function(body, start, len) {
        _message.data = body.slice(start, start+len);
    }

    var _result = _parser.execute(request, 0, request.length);

    if (_result != request.length) { 
        _message.error = _result; 
    }
    else {
        _message.error = false;
    }
    return _message;
}

var request = Buffer("GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: localhost\nContent-Length: 2\n\nHi\n\n");
result = parseMessage(request);
```

Note that the particular `IncomingMessage` class is parameterized with a `socket` and generally built around the idea of it being used within a server. The [code for parsing it](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_common.js) is somewhat messy to be reused as-is (to my taste).

Comment: Recent Node versions changed interface, now callbacks are assigned like `parser[HTTPParser.kOnHeaders] = function() {...}`

Answer (score 1):

Old topic, but I'll say something.

Exporting HTTPParser in own stuff (module or app) is not as simple, 'cause http library uses many internal local functions and constructors. Besides, HTTPParser itself is binded from C library and some helpers.

As I know http.parsers was **removed** from Node > 4, so the only way is to import all necessary stuff from http library.

For node 0.x there are easy way to import:

```
var parser = require("http").parsers.alloc();

parser.onIncoming = function(response) {
  console.log(response);
};

function parse(data) {
    var buffer = new Buffer(data);
    parser.execute(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
}
/**
 * tests
 */
parse("DELETE / HTTP/1.1\r\n");
parse("user-agent: curl\r\n");
parse("x-pingback:");
parse("12023\r\n");
parse("\r\n");

//response
{ _readableState: 
   { highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: false,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     calledRead: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     objectMode: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _maxListeners: 10,
  socket: undefined,
  connection: undefined,
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: false,
  headers: { 'user-agent': 'curl', 'x-pingback': '12023' },
  trailers: {},
  _pendings: [],
  _pendingIndex: 0,
  url: '/',
  method: 'DELETE',
  statusCode: null,
  client: undefined,
  _consuming: false,
  _dumped: false,
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  upgrade: false }
```

More info [here](https://gist.github.com/threez/8574532)

Also, thanks to @KT for elegant solution

Comment: Is there a solution for a newer node versions, like current LTS (v16)? `require("http").parsers` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

How about parsing it manually? The following is a sample of parsing http request from buffer. Need to convert the string to buffer firstly.

```
const data = Buffer.from([80, 79, 83, 84, 32, 104, 116, 116, 112, 58, 47, 47, 108, 111, 99, 97, 108, 104, 111, 115, 116, 58, 49, 50, 51, 52, 47, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 72, 84, 84, 80, 47, 49, 46, 49, 13, 10, 72, 111, 115, 116, 58, 32, 108, 111, 99, 97, 108, 104, 111, 115, 116, 58, 49, 50, 51, 52, 13, 10, 85, 115, 101, 114, 45, 65, 103, 101, 110, 116, 58, 32, 99, 117, 114, 108, 47, 55, 46, 55, 56, 46, 48, 13, 10, 65, 99, 99, 101, 112, 116, 58, 32, 42, 47, 42, 13, 10, 80, 114, 111, 120, 121, 45, 67, 111, 110, 110, 101, 99, 116, 105, 111, 110, 58, 32, 75, 101, 101, 112, 45, 65, 108, 105, 118, 101, 13, 10, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 45, 76, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 58, 32, 55, 13, 10, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 45, 84, 121, 112, 101, 58, 32, 97, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 47, 120, 45, 119, 119, 119, 45, 102, 111, 114, 109, 45, 117, 114, 108, 101, 110, 99, 111, 100, 101, 100, 13,10, 13, 10, 97, 61, 49, 38, 98, 61, 50]);


const delimIndex = data.indexOf('\r\n\r\n');
const lines = data.slice(0, delimIndex).toString('utf8').split('\r\n');
const startLine = lines[0];
const headers = lines.slice(1);
const body=data.slice(delimIndex + 4);

console.log(`${startLine}\n\n${headers.join('\n')}\n\n${body}`);
```